# Select Query is very slow on MySQL InnoDB Table having 160M+ rows

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, sql-optimization, amazon-aurora

Below are my table structure and index I have created. This table is having 160+ Million rows.

```
create table test
(
client_id varchar(100),
user_id varchar(100),
ad_id varchar(100),
attr0 varchar(250),
scp_id varchar(250),
attr1 datetime null default null,
attr2 datetime null default null,
attr3 datetime null default null,
attr4 datetime null default null,
sent_date date null default null,
channel varchar(100)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX idx_test_cid_sd ON test (client_id,sent_date);
CREATE INDEX idx_test_uid ON test (user_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_test_aid ON test (ad_id);
```

Below is the queries I am running:

```
select 
 count(distinct user_id) as users
 count(distinct ad_id) as ads
, count(attr1) as attr1
, count(attr2) as attr2
, count(attr3) as attr3
, count(attr4) as attr4
from test
where client_id = 'abcxyz'
and sent_date >= '2017-01-01' and sent_date < '2017-02-01';
```

Issues: Above query taking a lot of time more than 1 hour to return the result. When I saw the explain plan, it is using indexing and scanning only 8 millions record but the weird problem is it is taking more than 1 hour to return the results.

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong here or any suggestions on optimization part?

Comment: It has to grab all non-null values of 4 date columns of 8 million records

Comment: Why are you 'count'ing each separate column?

Comment: I need to show all the stats for a given time period. it's needed in our case. Can we do any optimization here?

Comment: While you should have a primary key, your indexes looks fine, and one hour is way too much for this query. I would suspect problems with your server configuration (pool sizes, sort buffer size, ...). Is this rds? How much memory do you have?

Comment: machine config: this is on aurora cluster: having 2 vCPU and 15GB RAM. Even on the normal EC2 instance, I tried allocating 80% RAM in innodb_buffer_pool but it is not working.

Comment: can you add execution plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Shrink the table to decrease the need for I/O.  This includes normalizing (where practical).  Using `AUTO_INCREMENT` of reasonable size for the various ids - instead of `VARCHAR`.  If you could explain those varchars, I could assess whether this is practical and how much benefit you might get.
- Have a `PRIMARY KEY`.  InnoDB does not like not having one.  (This will not help the particular problem.  If some combination of columns is `UNIQUE`, then make that the PK.  If not, use `id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT`; it won't run out of ids until after 4 billion.
- Change the `PRIMARY KEY` to make the query run faster.  (Though perhaps not faster than Simulant's "covering" index.)  But it would be less bulky:

Assuming you add `id .. AUTO_INCREMENT`, then:

```
PRIMARY KEY(client_id, sent_date, id),
INDEX(id)
```

How big (GB) is the data?  The indexes?  You *may* be at the cusp of "too big to cache", and paying for more RAM may help.

- Summary tables are great for `COUNT`, but not great for `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`.  That is, the counts could be done in seconds.  For Uniques, see [*my blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uniques).  Alas it is rather sketchy; ask for help.  It provides rolling up `COUNT(DISTINCT...)` as efficiently as `COUNT`, but with a 1-2% error.

The gist of a Summary table:  `PRIMARY KEY(client_id, day)` with columns for each day's counts.  Then getting the values for a month is `SUMming` the counts for 31 days.  Very fast.  More on [*Summary Tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables).

Answer (score 1):

You could add a [covering index](https://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=661727) containing to only the columns of the `where`-clause but also the selected columns for the result. In this way the query can read the whole result from the index and does not have to read a single row. Your columns used in the `where` clause need to stay as first columns of the index so this index can be used for the `where` restriction.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_test_cid_sd_cover_all ON test 
    (client_id, sent_date, user_id, ad_id, attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4);
```

However this index will be bigger than than your existing indexes, because nearly all your data of the table will exist as a copy in the index.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The query time drastically came down. Now same query showing results in 1.5 minutes. But still, it is not solving my requirement. Can we do any config changes (in my.cnf file) here to get faster results assuming all fields are filled with some values?  I want the results in 1 or 2 seconds.

Comment: 2 Seconds sounds unrealistic for me to examen 8 million records. Use the covering index and have enough RAM (and cache size configured) to hold the whole index at any time in the RAM.
I'm sorry, I don't know the variables to configure the cache sizes.